# css hover to clear linear gradient on background failed

Tags: html, css

I want to clear the dark linear gradient on my background image but tried this it won't work, it has flickering issue as well.

```css
.image {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
}

.image:hover {
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to reset gradient as well: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),` before url

Comment: @Smollet777 the transition won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this by using :before

```css
.image {
  position:relative;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.image:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  content:'';
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity:1;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
.image:hover:before{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution: transition: background-color 0.2s ease;

```css
.image 
{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.image:hover 
{
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```